# Removing part of character of filename

Tags: java, python, bash, perl, cmd

I am trying to remove part of a filename after a specific character.

> Current file names:

```
KM_003__Rheihe 4~DEL~389948.pdf
KM_004__Reite 2 und Reite 3~DEL~391098.pdf
KM_008__Grundriss~DEL~391042.pdf
```

> What I want it to be;

```
KM_003__Rheihe 4.pdf
KM_004__Reite 2 und Reite 3.pdf
KM_008__Grundriss.pdf
```

The files are located in C:\users\%username%\rename

Any help/pointers would greatly be appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Comment: Are you asking to rename the file - removing all charters between '~' and the '.' (not including the '.') ?

Comment: Also, question is tagged 'perl', 'java', 'python' and 'bash' - what kind of solution you are looking for ?

Comment: Well, you have tag **bash** in  bash you can use sub-string removal - it would be easier and will not require external tool. https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my approach change the path on what directory you want.

```
import os
import glob

path = 'c:\\rename'

files = [f for f in glob.glob(path + "**/*.pdf", recursive=True)]

for f in files:
    try:
        new = f.split('~')[0].replace(path,'').strip()
        os.rename(r'{}'.format(f), r'{}\{}.pdf'.format(path,new))
    except:
        print('cannot be renamed')
```

Comment: I receive an error  File "C:\Users\NN\Desktop\Split\split.py", line 8
    path = 'C:\Users\NN\Desktop\Split\\'
          ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: let me edit it, maybe because it reads  pdf file with no '~' characters in it

Comment: try the code again

Comment: I try again,  File "C:\Users\NN\Desktop\Split\split.py", line 9
    path = 'C:\Users\NN\Desktop\Split'
          ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: have you used double backslash on your path? C:\\Users\\NN\\Desktop\\Split

Answer (score 1):

So you want to remove a tilde ('~') followed by 'DEL', another tilde and a sequence of one or more digits.

In Perl, that would be:

```
s/~DEL~\d+//;
```

Putting that into a complete test program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  s/~DEL~\d+//;
  print;
}

__DATA__
KM_003__Rheihe 4~DEL~389948.pdf
KM_004__Reite 2 und Reite 3~DEL~391098.pdf
KM_008__Grundriss~DEL~391042.pdf
```

The output is:

```
KM_003__Rheihe 4.pdf
KM_004__Reite 2 und Reite 3.pdf
KM_008__Grundriss.pdf
```

Comment: Please, how you defined DATA ?

Comment: @Henri2: The `DATA` filehandle is just a quick hack that can be used to demonstrate a solution as I've done here. It returns the data that can be found following the `__DATA__` marker at the bottom of the Perl code. Obviously, you would read in your data using whatever mechanism is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `indexOf()` method to locate the `~` sign and use the `substring()` method to either cut out the part before the `~` or replace the part after the `~` with nothing.

Then I would rename the file or create a new file with the correct name and copy the contents of the old file to the new file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code directly now,

```
import re
import os
filenames = os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\\')
for filename in filenames:
    os.rename(r'C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\\'+ filename,r'C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\\'+ re.findall('([A-Za-z0-9_ ]*)~',filename)[0] +'.pdf')
```

Comment: how can defined the filename, i have more than 200000 files

Comment: I have edited the answer which will get names of all files and rename them.